# If / Else flow control in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, if-statement, dataframe

I am new to python and is working on logical statement.
My objective is to count the goal score by teams. (i.e. if a team scored a goal, I will assign 1 and the opponent will be assigned -1). Below is the snap shot of the data.
[Data is below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgKp2.jpg)

I wrote logical statement as follow:

```
if data['team']== data['hometeam_team1']:
   data['run_score'] = 1
else:
    data['run_score'] = -1
```

but it threw me value error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Can anyone advise?
Your help is much appreciated.
Thanks
Aung

Comment: Please do not post your data as an image. Post it as text in a code block so people can copy and paste it to try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You could create a runnable script with just a few rows and columns that demonstrates the problem. We could then edit that example and post a solution.

Comment: I think that the problem here is that `data['team']` (and also `data['hometeam_team1']`) returns the whole column and not a single element of the column, so it gives you a ValueError because it is a Series and not a single value.

Comment: Dear Jpp,
Sorry for any inconvenience caused to you.
This is the very first post, and I will take note of your suggestion in future posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The benefit of using `panda` is vectorised calculations. In other words, you *very rarely* need to use explicit `for` loops or `if` / `else` clauses to perform a calculation on each row.

Instead you can perform calculations on `pd.Series` objects. In this example, one efficient solution is to use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) which acts like a vectorised `if` / `else` clause:

```
import numpy as np

data['run_score'] = np.where(data['team']== data['hometeam_team1'], 1, -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this would work since you haven´t provided any data. But this is the general framework used to solve such problem. You can use `apply` function here.

```
data['run_score'] = data.apply(lambda row: 1 if row['team'] == row['hometeam_team1'] else -1, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice Yolo.